# ArgumentError: Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am fairly new to SQLAlchemy, and I am wondering if someone can help me decipher this error message:

> ERROR::sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table 'attacker_battles': no column named 'battles.battle_id' is present.

which it does in `Battles` table.

My code:

```
class Battles(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'battles'
    battle_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    starttime = Column(DateTime)
    endtime = Column(DateTime)

class Attacker_Battles(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attacker_battles'
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['battle_id','battles.battle_id'],
            ['attacker_id','player.player_id']),
        UniqueConstraint('battle_id','attacker_id', 'player_id', name= 'attacking_player_unique_id')
        )
    attacker_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    battle_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [first argument](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint.params.columns) to [`ForeignKeyConstaint`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint) should be a sequence of local columns, and [the second](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint.params.refcolumns) the matching sequence of referenced foreign columns. As it is now you have 2 lists of local, foreign pairs.

But: you're trying to create a composite foreign key constraint that references 2 or more tables, *which is not possible* in SQL. When you think about it, it is clear why: what [key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model#Key_constraints_and_functional_dependencies) would span multiple tables?

You can instead create separate foreign key constraints for `battle_id` and `attacker_id`, if that suits your model:

```
class Attacker_Battles(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attacker_battles'
    attacker_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.player_id'), primary_key=True)
    battle_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('battles.battle_id'), primary_key=True)
    player_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Also since you've defined that the primary key consists of the 3 columns, the unique constraint is redundant.